# Problem with react-hook-form not showing error until submit button is pressed

Tags: react-hook-form

This is the sample code from official site of react-hook-form:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-ts-5ksmm?file=/src/index.tsx

As you can see if you try it, the error is not displayed until the submit button is pressed.

Once the submit button is pressed, the error will be displayed in real time (in response to the onkeyup event).

Is this such a specification or a bug?
I want the error to be displayed in response to the onkeyup event from the beginning, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that I should set the `mode` option to `'all'`

```
useForm({
  mode: 'all'
})
```

https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#mode

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code help you:

```
useForm({
  mode: 'onChange'
})
```

[mode in documentations](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#mode)